# IIS Windows Authentication with DNS

Tags: iis, dns, windows-authentication, iis-10

I am using IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016.

I have successfully configured IIS to use Windows Authentication when going onto the site. This works well when using the IP address or hostname of the server.

However I am going to host several sites on the same server so I tried configuring some DNS records to point to the IP of the server (`A records`) and by defining a hostname in the IIS binding for that site I have managed to properly connect to the right site when using that name in the browser.

[image: Site binding configuration]

But for some reason, this breaks the Windows Authentication. When putting the username and password into the browser login-box it simply **fails to authenticate**.

[image: Browser authentication box fails to log in]

I read this answer but it didn't provide a solution ([IIS Windows Authentication weirdness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366649/iis-windows-authentication-weirdness))

I tried writing the username in different ways:

```
username
domain\username
domain.local\username
```

but it doesn't make any difference.

I looked at [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/973917/description-of-the-update-that-implements-extended-protection-for-auth) but it doesn't seem to be applicable.

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

Windows authentication is broken here because you are now accessing the application using a custom hostname and there are no SPN's set for it. You were able to successfully access the application earlier because you were accessing it using the servername directly . Also, please note when you access the application via IP address, you establish a connection via NTLM and not kerberos.

To fix your issue, you will simply have to configure a SPN. Enter the following command.

setspn -a http/hostname servername

Refer this article for more information

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jaws/spn-configurations-for-kerberos-authentication-a-quick-reference/

Comment: This worked for me. I also had to do a gpupdate /force-command + server restart after the setspn command.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off reverse DNS checking in the IIS metabase.  Windows authentication under the covers defaults to Kerberos, which might be conducting a reverse DNS check on the host name.  With host headers in play that check is going to fail.  To do this:

1. Open a command prompt.
2. Change the folder to C:\Inetpub\Adminscripts.
3. Type adsutil set w3svc/EnableReverseDNS FALSE, and then press ENTER.
4. Restart IIS.

Reference:  HOW TO: Enable Reverse DNS Lookup for IIS

Comment: I first added IIS 6 Management Compatibility as a Role to the server and ran the command you wrote. The command seemed to execute correctly but I still have the same problem. I restarted IIS. I am using IIS 10.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change what your application pool is running as. Go to the one that is giving you trouble, advanced settings. Look for the section labeled identity and try adding a domain admin account into that box. Once that happens recycle your app pool and restart your website. If it lets you authenticate you need to fix your SPN's for that website. I'll walk you through that if this is the route that fixes it